# What is default delete option in EF Core when a table have more than one foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a table that has more than one FK. This means that I use fluent API like below for more than one time.

```cs
builder.HasMany(c => c.Experts);
```

if I do not set the delete option for this table, it takes the default delete option. I want to know what delete option does it takes?

Comment: Cascade delete is default

Answer (score 0):

I Think Default Behavior In EFCore DeleteBehaviors Is CascadeDelete

Comment: Can you add a source for your statement?